# Delete the above line and replace it with other line after the condition become true

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-22.04

Please go through the below coding and clarify.

```
read -p "Enter the ip address: " ip
echo -e "\e[5mpinging...\e[25m"

ping -c 1 $ip &> /dev/null>1
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
        echo -e "\e[1;93m$ip\e[1;39m is reachable"
        else
        echo -e "\e[1;91m$ip\e[1;39m is not reachable"
        fi
```

When the above coding is executes, I need the program to wait 3 seconds, then say "**IP_ADDR is reachable**" also I need to replace the text "pinging..." to "completed" upon execution.

current output:[when the above script is executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFwmU.png)

needed output:[should replace the word "pinging..." with "completed"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMIyI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `\r` escape sequence that means, cursor go back to first character of the line.

So this will overwrite `pinging...` and it will not appear.

Here is how looks the script with this stategy.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the ip address: " ip
echo -ne "\e[5mpinging...\e[25m\r" # Note here \r
sleep 1
ping -c 1 $ip &> /dev/null>1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo -e "\e[1;93m$ip\e[1;39m is reachable"
else
  echo -e "\e[1;91m$ip\e[1;39m is not reachable"
fi
```

Hope it is helpful.